# How can I conditionally count fields in a CSV column

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-3.0

I have an CSV. On a specific column I would like to count the number of rows where I will find specific strings. I have placed the list of string inside a variable:

```
$list = 'test'
$tmpFiltre2 = 'c:\test.csv'
Import-Csv $tmpFiltre2 -Delimiter "," | Where-Object {
    $_.msg -and $list -like $_.msg
} | group msg -NoElement
```

I end up with the correct result error messages are first displayed: I have not listed all the possible values that the `msg` column will contain)

> The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid: [120] board
>   At c:\myscript.PS1:134 char:70

Some field have square brackets inside the column.

CSV file look like this

```
msg,Personn
test,bill
120 test,eli
test test,eli
[1] test,bill
[120] board,bill
alarm [1],Jo
```

The output will look like:

```
test,4
```

As there are 4 rows, each of them containing at least once the string "test".

Comment: _I have not listed all the possible values that the msg column will contain_ You have not listed any. Show some example and perhaps `-like` is not the ideal operator for this.

Comment: To ensure we answer this the way you want to we need to see some sample output. I do not understand the relationship between your rows. What you are doing now is just filtering out some records and even that I do not fully understand. Your count would be 1 for each remaining record. Do you want to know the count of "120 test" records in that file?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$list = @('test', 'alarm')
import-csv "C:\temp\test.csv" | foreach{
    $msg=$_.msg
    $list | where {$msg -like "*$_*"} | select @{N="WordFounded";E={$_}}, @{N="Msg";E={$msg}}
} | group WordFounded
```

Comment: I works if I have only one element in my list containing a single word, but no longer works when strings contain words sperated by space: $list='ntp,test 120' as in this case no result is displayed, as the coma separated list is considered as an entire string I believe.

Comment: It works !! Thanks . I added -NoElement at the end to remove data I did not want to display.